# Informatica Powerecenter 9.1.0 Decimal Scale Issue

Tags: oracle, decimal, type-conversion, truncate, informatica-powercenter

I am having issues while converting the decimal values to varchar through Informatica 9.1. Both my source and target are in Oracle.
It automatically reduces the value of the digit by "0.01" when I use truncate function.
My Source data type is Amount(Decimal(38,15)); I am using the following expression to convert it to string after I truncate it as follows: TO_CHAR(TRUNC(Amount,2)).
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgJak.png)

My target data type is varchar(255). And below is the snap of data in target.
For 9.52 amount after truncation the value changed to 9.51 as seen in snap shot.
[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhgb9.png)

Could anyone help to sort out the issue?

Comment: This does not seem right! are you sure there is no other logic on that field?

Comment: Apart from truncating the value like TRUNC(Amt,2) and then converting it to varchar; there is no logic.

Answer (score 1):

This might just be the effect of the way you're viewing your data. For example, let's assume your value is 9.5185 - upon viewing in the client tool, it will be displayed rounded to 9.52. Whereas the TRUNC function will cut off the last digits, leaving it as 9.51.

Comment: As I earlier stated the value which is coming from source is 9.520000000000000 and except truncating it to 2 decimal places and converting it to varchar there is no other logic.

Comment: How do you know the value is 9.520000000000000? What's the way you view/check it? Some applications do implicit rounding before displaying the values.

Answer (score 1):

Maciej is most likely right... in a lot of applications what gets represented as 9.52 is actually stored 9.51999999999. Could you do us a favour and truncate to 10 places instead of 2 and post the result?

Answer (score 0):

As stated before is the way to_char function behave and how number round is handled in Informatica.
This could help if you want more "precision" and have a less rounding

From Informatica PowerCenter Guide:

> The PowerCenter Integration Service converts decimal ports with
>   precision greater than 15 to a double and returns TO_CHAR values in
>   scientific notation.
>
> To avoid this, you must enable high precision. When you enable high
>   precision, PowerCenter supports decimals up to a precision of 28.

Note the high precision is a check box into the workflow under propety tab

To resolve this issue select the enable high precision for the session as follows:

In Workflow Manager, open the session task for editing.
Click the Properties tab.
Select the Enable high precision option.
Close the session and save.

[PowerCenter session using TO_CHAR on decimal field](https://kb.informatica.com/solution/3/Pages/13999.aspx)